# Clan wars ranking in Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

In my clan we have 4 players who are almost fully maxed th10s. My question is after we are all 4 completelly maxed, who will be ranked 1st in clan wars? How is that determined?

Answer (score -1):

I'm almost certain that your ranks will be determined solely on trophies. I have seen this in several clans, where the clan standings directly translate to the clan war map. If you are asking about the end result, or the ranking after both attacks have been made, that is determined by performance. Hope this answer helps!

Comment: I somehow doubt it, because from the [FAQs](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/232849-Clan-Wars-FAQ), it is mentioned that "The bases are ordered from highest to lowest strength. The highest strength war bases are at the top of the war map. Trophies have no influence on the order of bases.", so I believe it is something else if two villages are tied in terms of defensive strength.

Comment: I guess my clan's strongest bases translated to rankings as well... post that as an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough information to confirm the basis on which the village position on the war map is determined. I know it is not based on a few things, but cannot say for sure what is the decisive factor.

Comment: ill know in a week or 2 and ill let you guyz know.. My guess is that once we are all completelly maxed, xp(lvl) will kick in..